# How to change vertical scroll bars in horizontal site

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

#### What's happening right now

I've created a [single-page horizontal scrolling site](http://heavenlyinspirations.us.s52928.gridserver.com/) that shows a single section at a time.  Each section has a different amount of content and different heights. Currently the scroll the vertical scroll bar accommodates for the longest section in the site. Which is totally expected.

#### What I am trying to do

I want the vertical scroll bars to be relative the current visible section. So there would not be excessive vertical scrolling on a short section. I hope this makes sense, I've seen it before but can't find an example online.

#### What I've tried, but didn't work

```
$("ul#nav li a").click(function() {
  $("ul#nav li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  // Get the height of the element and set max-height
  var section_id = $(this).attr("href")
  section_id = $('div' + section_id).height();
  $("body").attr('style', 'height: ' + section_id + 'px !important; max-height: ' + section_id + 'px !important;');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me. I'm sure there's a better way, but this got the job done for now! Basically I created an object that stores each sections hash and height then reference those to resize each section to the height of the active section. Of note it seemed that when I reset the height of the sections I also had to set the width again too.

```
$("ul#nav li a").click(function() {
    $("ul#nav li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var section_key = $(this).attr("href")
    changeSectionH(section_key)
});

var sections = {};
$("div.section").each(function(index) {
        var section_id = '#' + $(this).attr("id");
        var section_h = $(section_id).height();
        sections[section_id] = section_h;
});

function changeSectionH(key){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $("div.section").attr('style', 'height: ' + sections[key] + 'px !important; max-height: ' + sections[key] + 'px !important; width: ' + windowWidth + 'px; overflow-y:hidden;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to change the css on the elements that are not within the current view frame to be display:none.

*edit*

Maybe a better choice would be to wrap them in a div that has

```
 overflow-y: scroll
```

and the height on that div would be your max height.  Then when they moved into focus, you could change the CSS properties as needed to display it normally.

Comment: Wouldn't that take out the horizontal scrolling aspect then?

Comment: You're probably right - maybe my edited suggestion would work better for you.